# create construct in class inherited by model or controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm a java programmer and now I want to learn CodeIgniter framework to apply to my php application. I saw many examples on the web and I have a question. When I create a model or a controller, I have to inherit from CI_Model and CI_Controller but my question is: do I have to always create the construct in every model o controller? So I mean I have to put in every class

```
function __construct()
{
  parent::__constuct();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't override the `__construct`, it is not necessary. But if you override it, you need to call `parent::__constuct();`, php will not call the parent constructor automatically.

Comment: So what I say is: is it necessary to create a  construct in subclasses inherited from model and controller?

Comment: @eng_mazzy If you don't want to override the parent's constructor, it is not necessary.

Comment: but I would which could be the advantages in overring in php the construct of the super class...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

I don't know how is it in java. But in php if no construct method is found in the child class it will call the parent one

Comment: so why, as I saw in many examples, there is a construct in the class ?

Comment: @eng_mazzy They are almost the auto-generated codes. It is only to remind you that the constructor of parent class has done something, so don't forget call parent's constructor if you override it. Any way, I don't like write such code.

Comment: @yokoloko So you're suggesting to not implement class that has the construct...right?